# Parsing Parquet files with Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, parquet

What would be the correct approach to parsing [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) files with Perl?

CPAN seems devoid of any module to do this, aside from some logic inside S3 Amazon Web Services modules that don't offer any parsing code I can find.

Comment: Are these binary files? See [How to parse binary data with Perl](https://www.perl.com/article/how-to-parse-binary-data-with-perl/) for an approach.

Comment: @HåkonHægland - they are very specific format for Apache Hadoop

Comment: there seems to be a C++ library https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp that could be wrapped in a perl interface with perl XS

Comment: It could be built as an [Alien](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::Build::Manual::Alien) and then used via XS or [FFI](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus) but the third party dependencies for building look somewhat complex.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a single module that would do this, but there is a path forward.  First, note that the Parquet [format](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format#file-format) has a [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) [specification](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift), which is parseable by [Thrift::IDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thrift::IDL).  That, coupled with either [Convert::Binary::C](https://metacpan.org/pod/Convert::Binary::C) or the link posted by@HåkonHægland should get you started.